# fix terminal vim colours (on focus lost)

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gnome

When setting up Ubuntu 12.10 64bit (with gnome-terminal 3.6.0) I noticed that my vim colours mess up in the terminal as soon as the terminal loses focus. Everything is fine when using < C-z> and fg, or switching tabs; I've only seen this issue so far with losing focus. I've installed the plugin [CSExact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), and calling :CSExactColors fixes things right up, but apparently you can't set autocmd's for FocusGained/FocusLost events in terminal vim.

[image: terminal issue]

The strange thing is that I have vim on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit (with gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1) on my other computer, with the exact same settings, and this issue has never shown up before. Any ideas on how I can fix this, or a good workaround? Thanks :)

Comment: Does this happen with other colorschemes as well ?

Comment: It does, even with the default colorscheme

Comment: Just for fun try to make a separate account and see if it happens from there. After all, there could be a *glitch* (zing!) in a config file.

Comment: lol like the glitch reference. Its definitely my CSExact plugin for vim, as soon as I removed it the colours stay the same when the focus is lost. However I feel hesitant to blame csexact, since csexact simply changes the colours when loading. This must be an issue with the terminal right?

Comment: what does `:set background?` say before and after the loss of focus?

Comment: It's light both before and after, however I tried changing it to dark and came up with the same results (but different colour change)

Comment: @glitchyme did you find a fix for this by any chance?
Here is a report about it in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1191238

Comment: @blueyed Thanks for finding this, I'll be keeping an eye on the thread. In the meantime I've swapped over the Sakura https://launchpad.net/sakura